# Measuring Average Distance Polygons Extend Past Line

Tags: polygon, distance, buffer, line

I need to find the average distance of a set of polygons that extend beyond a line for risk management purposes.  There are multiple polygons representing potential spill zones and different pipeline segments associated with these areas.  I am attempting to find an average distance from the furthest part of the polygon to the line.  This information does not need to follow any elevation contours or other geographic features.  I simply need a way to find the average so I can create a meaningful buffer for some data I need to clip.  Can someone suggest a method for doing so?

Comment: What software are you using? Can you give us a picture of what you're after?

Comment: "an average distance from the furthest part of the polygon to the line": This feels contradictory. The furthest distance from a polygon to a line is achieved by a vertex of the convex hull of the polygon. I don't see how "average" makes sense, unless you want to average over all polygons, or average over all line segments.

Comment: I am using ArcGIS 10.2.2 for Desktop.  [Here's](http://imgur.com/aaGdb7Z) an example of the distances I need (yellow). 
 I think I described this poorly.  I'm trying to find the furthest distance, as the crow flies, the polygon extends away from the pipe in multiple places.  I will then take those distances and get an average from them.